# API Key and RESTKit

Tags: cocoa-touch, restkit, api-key

I'm using [**RESTKit**](http://restkit.org/) for a service that was created for me. The model in JSON for my user is:

```
{
    "api_key" : "123456"
    "user" : {
        "username" : "user1",
        "email"    : "me@email.com",
        "name"     : "name1",
        "surname"  : "surname1"
    }
}
```

I need introduce the `api_key` if I want to GET an user `/users/1.json`. I read in the documentation about set an app-wide API key HTTP header.

The example is:

```
[client setValue:@"123456" forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-RESTKIT-API-KEY"];
```

Is it the right way to do this? How can I discover my `@"X-RESTKIT-API-KEY"` of my service? (not api_key value, I search the string to replace `@"X-RESTKIT-API-KEY"` for my service)

Comment: what is being asked here? Do you want to know how to retrieve the supplied api key on your server side?

Comment: No, I don't. I ask how I can retrieve the name for the HTTP Header API Key in my service. I know the api_key value, I need the correct string to replace @"X-RESTKIT-API-KEY" in my service.

Comment: well, the name of the header field in question depends entirely on your backend. Do you interface with your private api or something publicly available?

Comment: It's a private service. It was created for me by a hire developer. He doesn't know where he have to looking for this name. I'm iOS developer and I don't know anything about his backend. I could ask him something if you say me what.

Comment: Well, i guess your hire developer have to implement the mechanism to accept api key via header. He chooses the name of the header and he tells that to you afterwards. Restkit can not influence your api if it is not ready for this kind of authentication

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, for that sample GET request, I suggest you to use RKClient object. I will give you some example:

```
#import <RestKit/RestKit.h>
#import "JSONKit.h"

RKClient* client = [RKClient clientWithBaseURL:@"http://yourdomainwhereisapi.com"];
```

and anywhere in you app (because RKCLient is singleton object) you can call:

```
// Here you need to define delegate in header (because delegate is self)
// Declare delegate in .h file with <RKRequestDelegate>
[[RKClient sharedClient] get:@"/some/api/call.json" delegate:self];
```

You must to define delegate method:

```
- (void)request:(RKRequest*)request didLoadResponse:(RKResponse*)response {
      // where you handle response object
      // sample how to make NSDictionary from JSON response
      NSDictionary *deserializedData = [[response bodyAsString] objectFromJSONString];

      // Now you can get anything from this NSDictionary:
      NSLog("%@", [deserializedData objectForKey:@"api_key"];
}
```

P.S. Anyway, you can take a look at RestKit wiki to see basic examples: [RestKit Wiki tutorial](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Tutorial-%3a-Introduction-to-RestKit)

Comment: First, thanks @kondormit for your answer. I set my clientWithBaseURL but if I want to GET call.json, the services need an api_key. I know the value of that api_key but I don't know how I can set in RESTKit. :-(
If I do GET without api_key, I get forbidden message: {"error":"Forbidden"}

Comment: Hmm, I don't understand you well. If you are doing GET you are not sending nothing. If you are doing POST you are sending some object with post (params) and you can parse response. Please be specific (give me real example) so I can give you solution.

Comment: If I do GET an user, I need give to my service a api value for access to these data. The service was created that way for my hired backend developer.

Comment: You need to send classic parrams with GET? Something like google.com?search=something